# How to delete all .DS_Store when packaging with electron-packager?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

When building packages with electron-packager on Mac OS X, I want to ignore all .DS_store files in my project folder.

.DS_Store should not be included in my packages.

Should I use an option of electron-packager or an other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ignore](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#ignore) option of electron-packager to skip files matching a certain regular expression:

```
electron-packager . MyApp \
    --asar \
    --platform=darwin \
    --arch=x64 \
    --prune=true \
    --ignore='\.DS_Store'
```

The backslashes at the end of each line allow to continue the command on the next line. You escape the newline, so make sure there are no characters (e.g. spaces) after the backslash.

The backslash in the ignore parameter escapes the `.`, which otherwise matches any character. Once it's escaped, it matches only the character `.`.

Comment: Hey - do you know if it is possible ignore multiple files through one ignore directive or does it have to be repeated for each file to be ignored (the way I am doing it now). i.e.  `-ignore= '.DS_Store, ./dist, ./build'` or something like that? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: @NoGrabbing Since it's a regular expression, you could use ``--ignore='\.DS_Store|\./dist|\./build'``

Comment: @snwflk - awesome, thanks! I saw that regex is supported but didn't know how to do it.